# COLOREAR una JLIST

Tags: java

hace dias estoy buscando en google una forma para ponerle un color permanente a una celda en especifico de una JList, alguien sabe como es el metodo? Desde ya, muchas gracias

Comment: Por favor, edita la pregunta para limitarla a un problema específico con suficiente detalle para identificar una respuesta adecuada.

Comment: Compruebe si la creación de su propio `ListCellRenderer` ayuda. Puede poner iconos, definir fuentes y colores para su JList cuando lo use.